# Can't install RMagick 4.0.0. Can't find ImageMagick with pkg-config on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, imagemagick, gem, pkg-config

Trying to install pdfbeads on Ubuntu LTS 16.04 with the command
$ gem install pdfbeads
I'm getting the error message
"ERROR: Can't install RMagick 4.0.0. Can't find ImageMagick with pkg-config"

Below between the separators is the corresponding stdout.

---

$ sudo gem install pdfbeads

Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.10.7
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR: Error installing pdfbeads:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/enemem/.gem/gems/rmagick-4.0.0/ext/RMagick

/snap/bin/ruby -I /snap/ruby/172/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200127-10722-yuiix4.rb extconf.rb
checking for brew... no
checking for pacman... no
checking for gcc... yes
checking for pkg-config... yes

ERROR: Can't install RMagick 4.0.0. Can't find ImageMagick with pkg-config

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/snap/ruby/172/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

---

Checked the mkmf.log file but it containe the same info, verbatim.

Then I tried to use the command

$ pkg-config --modversion imagemagick

and got this output:

---

Package imagemagick was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `imagemagick.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'imagemagick' found

---

Following up on this suggestion I tried to find where imagemagick is on my system by running:

$ sudo locate -b '\imagemagick*'

and got the output:

---

/usr/lib/mime/packages/imagemagick
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/imagemagick-6.q16:display-im6.q16.desktop
/usr/share/app-install/desktop/imagemagick:display-im6.desktop
/usr/share/bug/imagemagick
/usr/share/cups/ppdc/imagemagick.defs
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-6.q16
/usr/share/doc/imagemagick-common
/usr/share/menu/imagemagick
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-main/64x64/imagemagick-6.q16_display-im6.q16.png
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-main/64x64/imagemagick_display-im6.q16.png
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-security-main/64x64/imagemagick-6.q16_display-im6.q16.png
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-security-main/64x64/imagemagick_display-im6.q16.png
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-updates-main/64x64/imagemagick-6.q16_display-im6.q16.png
/var/lib/app-info/icons/ubuntu-xenial-updates-main/64x64/imagemagick_display-im6.q16.png
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-6.q16.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-6.q16.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-common.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-common.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-common.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-common.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-common.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick-common.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/imagemagick.prerm

---

Version of the imagemagick package on my system is 6.8.9.9

---

$ sudo apt search ImageMagick | grep installed

imagemagick/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed]
imagemagick-6.q16/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed]
imagemagick-common/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 all [installed]
libgraphicsmagick++-q16-12/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.3.23-1ubuntu0.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgraphicsmagick-q16-3/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.3.23-1ubuntu0.5 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libimage-magick-perl/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 all [installed,automatic]
libimage-magick-q16-perl/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagick++-6.q16-5v5/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libmagickcore-6.q16-2/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed]
libmagickwand-6.q16-2/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 amd64 [installed]
perlmagick/xenial-updates,xenial-updates,xenial-security,xenial-security,now 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15 all [installed,automatic]

---

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ERROR: Can't install RMagick 4.0.0. Can't find ImageMagick with
>   pkg-config

EDIT : Please install `libmagickcore-6.q16-dev` (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15), which is the development files for your installed "imagemagick (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.15)" : `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ImageMagick.pc`, etc. etc. files.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libmagickcore-6.q16-dev >>> https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/amd64/libmagickcore-6.q16-dev/filelist

May be you have to uninstall the older version `graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat` and the dependency `libgraphicsmagick1-dev`.

Comment: Thanks, that was quite helpful, that seems to be the missing piece.

Comment: However, standard version that I get by running

sudo apt install graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat

is 1.3.23 which is too old - now I'm getting the error

"ERROR: Can't install RMagick 4.0.0. You must have ImageMagick 6.7.7 or later."

Please advise how to go about getting the later version. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, graphicsmagick-libmagick-dev-compat is an older version. Please see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job. Greatly appreciated.